# Running command on "post-update-cmd" in Symfony2 project

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I need to run two commands after I run `composer update`, one if a Linux console command that calls a `.sh` file and the second one is a `php app/console` command. Is that possible by doing something in `composer.json` file? I notice this lines:

```
"post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets"
        ]
```

But don't know if this is the right way. Take as example for 1st command: `/home/data.sh` and for 2nd command `php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append`, any advice on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include these commands in `post-update-cmd` directive like this:

```
"post-update-cmd": [
    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
    "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
    "/home/data.sh",
    "php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append"
]
```

More info: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Comment: Add `--ansi` to your command to get output formatting with colors.